# Forms Authentication and SSO

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, ws-federation

Created a web based application which needs to integrate forms authentication and SSO. Currently forms authentication will validate all the registered users. 
What I need is to integrate SSO as well in to the application. ie, If the user not authenticated then redirect to identity server (Okta) configured with WS-Fed and added the application, validate and response to landing page. Please can you help on this. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: There's entire companies devoted to providing this type of service to businesses. 1) I don't work for one. 2) If I did, *I'd charge you for it*.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain this statement " If the user not authenticated then redirect to identity server (Okta) configured with WS-Fed and added the application"?

Please see this link https://github.com/okta/okta-music-store. Under section "Adding Single-sign on to your Music Store" you can see how C# sdk can be used to implement single sign on.

Essentially what you need is a cookieToken from Okta. Using cookieToken as one time token and a redirect url (Can be your app url) you can use /login/sessionCookieRedirect?token=&redirectUrl=. This will create active session with Okta and redirect your user to your app or redirect uri.

Cookie token is obtained via series of two calls. Authentication that gives you session token in response. Session token is exchanged for cookie token via create session call.